# Declare @IBOutlet with swift 2 available attribute

Tags: swift, swift2

How can I declare an `@IBOutlet` for a view, which is not available for all my destination targets in Xcode 7? Xcode suggests to supplement the entire class with the `@available(iOS 8.0, *)` attribute, which I definitely not want. I want to be able to make it kind of an optional view, which is available from code if the target runs a recent iOS version.

Here is a shortened version of the code:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var checkmarkView: PopupView!

    private func showPopupView() {
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

@available(iOS 8.0, *)
class PopupView: UIVisualEffectView {
    ...
}
```

Comment: You can't mark the outlet declaration with `@available`. You'll have to confine the availability limitation to some other portion of your code.

Comment: You could declare the outlet as `UIView` and then cast it to the specific class in an `@available(...)` block but I think you will have a loading problem anyway when the nib is going to be instantiated.

Comment: You could use two UIViewController subclasses, and choose which one to instantiate depending on OS availability.

Comment: That is a good idea, but how can I use it with the storyboard then?

Comment: So if I created a toolbar using UIStackView, which is only available 9.0+, then.. I have to 1)create simpler version that doesn't use UIStackView, 2) programmatically load either version depending on current iOS version. Ugh. So much work :(